# wordpress: query to select the last post from more than 1 specific category

Tags: sql, wordpress, categories

I need to select the last post from 3 different categories.
Till now, I've got a query like this:

```
select ID, t.term_id term_id, post_title, post_content, t.slug as category 
from e_posts p
inner join e_term_relationships tr on p.ID = tr.`object_id`
inner join e_term_taxonomy tt on tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
inner join e_terms t on t.term_id = tt.term_id 
where tt.taxonomy = "category" and t.term_id IN(4,670,158)
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

If I try to group by term_id, I get the first post from each term (category). Even if I order by date. What can I do? I guess it's not too hard but can't figure out..

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY ID DESC?

Answer (score 1):

You problem relates to [<kbd>greatest-n-per-group</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag (take a look) you need to get the most recent posts where your criteria matches. So here is your solution: get the posts with their max date self join by using `p.ID = tr.`object_id`AND p.post_date = tr.post_date` so it takes care to get the recent posts

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.ID, 
  t.term_id term_id, 
  p.post_title, 
  p.post_content, 
  t.slug AS category 
FROM 
  e_posts p
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
     etr.*,
     pp.ID,
     MAX(pp.post_date) post_date 
   FROM 
     e_posts pp 
INNER JOIN 
  e_term_relationships etr 
ON 
  pp.ID = etr .`object_id`  
GROUP BY 
  pp.ID,etr.term_taxonomy_id) tr  
ON 
  (p.ID = tr.`object_id` AND p.post_date = tr.post_date)
INNER JOIN 
  e_term_taxonomy tt 
ON 
  tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN 
  e_terms t 
ON 
  t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE
  tt.taxonomy = "category" AND 
  t.term_id IN(4,670,158)
```

Comment: Thank you but it throws an error (Unknown column 'tr.object_id' in 'on clause')

Comment: @Stratboy there was a mistake the on condition fir inner query should be `ON pp.ID = etr.object_id`

Comment: Get another error: Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous

Please if you edit, keep the table names as I edited.

Comment: In select the id fields needs the table reference so i added and haven't changed the table name

Comment: Ok now there are no errors but it doesn't work, get the same result as mine: with all those 'eventi'. If I take a shot, it's just like the one you can see in my original post

Comment: @Stratboy can add [sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your sample dataset and table definitions